# Adaptar vídeo que esta en un iframe

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3, video, iframe

En mi página principal tengo un iframe el cual hace enlace a una página en la que se visualiza un vídeo:

**index.php**

```
<style>
.ren-video{
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    min-height:1px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item{
    height: 550px;
}
</style>

<div class="ren-video">
    <p>Película:</p>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <?php
      $video = "dory.mp4";
    ?>
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="video.php?var=<?php echo base64_encode($video); ?>" id="vIFrame" allowfullscreen style="height: 500px;"> 
    </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**video.php**

```
<style>
body{
    background-color: #fff;
}
video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
</style>

<?php
 $video = base64_decode($_GET["var"]);
?>

<video controls autoplay name="media">
    <source src="archivos/<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

El problema aquí es que cuando visualizo el vídeo la imagen no ocupa todo el ancho, como pueden ver en la imagen se ve el fondo blanco de la página que contiene el vídeo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que la imagen del vídeo ocupe todo el ancho?? Estoy usando bootstrap 3

Comment: Le estás asignando un alto al iframe del video, éste debe ser automático, porque ya le estás definiendo un valor al width. Cambia este valor y nos cuentas cómo te va.

Comment: @JheymanMejia así es y lo asigno porque si lo dejo en auto o lo dejo sin height se ve muy alto y no lo quiero tan alto, la altura la quiero así como se aprecia en la imagen

Comment: Elimina ese height del iframe y asígnale un ancho del 100%, eso soluciona el problema. También elimínalo de la clase de Bootstrap.

Comment: @JheymanMejia hace grande el vídeo y el tamaño que quiero es el que se ve en la imagen

Comment: El tamaño que se ve en la imagen no ocupa todo el ancho, **¿no es eso justamente lo no quieres?** Si ocupa todo el ancho de su contenedor, es claro se va a hacer más grande, tanto el `width` como el `height`.

Comment: @JheymanMejia lo que quiero es que ese cuadro negro que es el de la imagen del vídeo ocupe los espacios laterales en blanco que se observan, quiero conservar ese alto que es de 500px

Comment: Te entiendo, pero entonces para poder ocupar todo el ancho vas a tener que recortar el alto del video, quieras o no. A menos que "estires" el video lo cual lo deformará (es más, ni creo que se pueda hacer eso con un video y CSS). Lo que va a suceder es que el video hará un zoom interno cada vez mayor si se aumenta el ancho del navegador. Ya entras con otro problema y es la **accesibilidad** de tu sitio. Al final sería algo así como aplicar `background-size: 100%;` a tu video, lo cual no es para nada conveniente.

Comment: @JheymanMejia ya he dado un alto al vídeo y se ve exactamente igual que en la imagen